# How to send an Ajax request in Axios/Vue in a way that is resemble a normal form POST request?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, axios

I am using a POST request with Vue and Axios, and want to send in POST parameters in a way that they are intepreted by the Servlet on the serverside, as they were sent from a normal html form. However, it convert the variables into a single JSON request in the body of the query. Is it possible to use Axios header to prevent this, and what is the syntax for putting in the variables then?

Comment: It's got its own section in the Axios documentation: https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format